# Try to replace a specific value in a dataframe, but does not overwritte it

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this `orders_total`:

```
    price   amount  side
0   0.003019    100 bids
0   0.003143    100 asks
```

When I try to replace a specific value by doing the following:

```
orders_total[orders_total.side == 'asks'].loc[index].amount -= 10
```

But when I print the dataframe it is not changed... any idea why?
thanks!

Comment: why do you use  `orders_total[orders_total.side == 'asks'].loc[index].amount -= 10` and not  `orders_total.loc[index, 'amount'] -= 10` ?

Comment: in other words, you are filtering rows of the daframe with a condition but you end up selecting a specific row. Your solution does not work because it is changing the value of a copy of the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to modify in-place when you really are ending up with a `copy` of the dataframe, not a view, and hence the original dataframe remains unchanged. This is known as *chained indexing*.

To find out more on this check: [Returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

You want to index along both axis using `.loc`. This will lead to a single call to `__getitem__` which will return a *view* of the dataframe, and changes to this view will be reflected on the original dataframe:

```
orders_total.loc[orders_total.side == 'asks', 'amount'] -= 10
```

Comment: ah ok I see my mistake! indeed it works now, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget you can upvote answers too @Viktor.w :)